# Internal versus External Storage

Tags: android, storage, external, internal

I have read so many theories about saving a file to the internal storage and external storage that I don't know exactly any more what to do.
I created a PDF file with droidtext that I want to e-mail as an attachment in the chosen e-mail app.
This is no problem. I succeeded in this, however... I only can do it with the external storage.
So, I create a PDF, put it in the external storage with `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()`.
However, if no external storage is available I want to save the PDF on the internal storage.
I did it like this so far: 
External (working perfectly):

```
pdf = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + java.io.File.separator + fileName);
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(pdf));
```

Internal storage:

```
pdf = new File(fileName);
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_PRIVATE));
```

With both having `Document document = new Document();`.
The Internal memory method delivers no error whatsoever, but I am not sure if the file is saved internally.
Also, I think that because it is saved internally, the mail app will not be able to select it as an attachment.
I can't test this because my emulator has no mail app. Nor can I go through the content on the device. Nor do I own a device that has no external storage...

What is the best way to solve this? Force users to have external storage or are there other ways to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

"What is the best way to solve this? Force users to have external storage or are there other ways to solve this?"...I'm not certain, but I think you have no choice but to force users to have external storage to be able to email an attachment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I hope someone can answer me with 100% certainty.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use MODE_PRIVATE to save to internal storage or the email app won't be able to access the file. You'll have to use MODE_WORLD_READABLE.

To get the directory of where the file is stored use Context.getFilesDir() (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29)

You can also just install an email app on the emulator to test this. Just download an apk and install it via adb.